# Let $A = \{ 2, 5, 9\}$. Let $K = \{ F ∈ S_9 | F(a) = a, ∀a ∈ A \}$. Determine order of $K$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

**Question: See title**

---

First off, what is K exactly? My guess: it's just the identity function with order $1$. If it's not the identity function, how would I calculate the order?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $K$ is the set of permutations on nine elements such that very specifically $2$ appears in the second spot, $5$ appears in the fifth spot, and $9$ appears in the ninth spot.  The rest of the spots however are not necessarily fixed.  So, for example $123456789$ is a valid permutation in $K$.  So too is $827351469$.  Now... as for how many such permutations there are., just use rule-of-product in the exact same way that you would have derived the formula that there are $n!$ permutations of $n$ elements in the first place, only this time, remember the restrictions on where $2,5,9$ are placed.

Comment: As an aside, $\{F\in S_9\mid F(a)=a,\forall a\in \{1,2,3,\dots,9\}\}$ would indeed consist only of the identity function.  $A$ however is specifically $\{2,5,9\}$ and not $\{1,2,3,4,\dots,9\}$.

Comment: @JMoravitz Thank you for explaining. I'm confident to say I completely understand the problem now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** An arbitrary element $\alpha \in F$ has the form:
$$\alpha = \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 \\
x_1 & 2 & x_3 & x_4 & 5 & x_6 & x_7 & x_8 & 9
\end{pmatrix}
$$

where $x_1, x_3, x_4, x_6, x_7, x_8$ is some permutation of the numbers in the set $\{1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8\}$.

Comment: Thank you. This is more than helpful!

Answer (score 0):

It is all about cosets of $Sym(9)$. Lets look at easier example:

Take the set  A = $\{f\in Sym(9)$ : $f(2)=3 \}$.

Actually  A=$(23)Sym\{ 1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}=(23) \langle (13),(13456789)\rangle$.
Every set which is look like A is actually a coset.

Look at the set B= $\{f\in Sym(9)$ : $f(2)=2 \}$. B is exactly $(22)Sym\{1,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\} = \langle (13),(13456789)\rangle$.

For your question you look

$$\{f\in Sym(9) : f(2)=2 \} \cap \{f\in Sym(9) : f(3)=3 \} \cap \{f\in Sym(9) : f(9)=9 \} = (22)(33)(99) Sym\{1,4,5,6,7,8\}$$ which has 6 coset. You can find them by multiply $Sym\{1,4,5,6,7,8\}$ with $ Id,(23),(39),(29),(239),(293)$.I think the analogy is clear.

You can also find the set $\{ f\in Sym(9): f[\{1,2,3\}]=\{1,2,3\} \}$.